# Are there differences between A=BCD and A="BCD" in Bash shell?

Tags: bash, shell

I can define `Bash shell` variables in the following ways:

```
[root@localhost ~]# A=BCD
[root@localhost ~]# echo $A
BCD
[root@localhost ~]# A="BCD"
[root@localhost ~]# echo $A
BCD
```

From the `echo` output, I can't see differences between `A=BCD` and `A="BCD"`, so I think they are same. Is it right?

BTW, if they are same, `A=` and `A=""` should be same too. Is it right?

Comment: There is no difference between A=BCD and A="BCD" and A='BCD' and A='B'CD and A=B'CD' and A=B"C"D ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case there are no differences because BCD has no character with special meanings for the shell. Quotes are use for preventing some characters from being interpreted by the shell, as whitespaces, pipes, ampersands and dollars. Try including some of them inside your examples and you will see the difference. Quotes are use for shielding script inputs from whitespaces and empty strings, too. Try this:

```
A="A B C" ; echo $A
A=A B C   ; echo $A
```

My advice: Use them always. They never hurt and make things more predictable by making the empty string explicit.